# dns problems in self managed aws ec2 cluster with aws-vpc-cni

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I'm new to k8s and I've been trying to learn it. I faced a problem with trying to setup [aws-vpc-k8s-cni](https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s) on my fresh k8s cluster with `coredns`. Here's the problem in detail.

#### Cluster & Network Architecture

The cluster setup consists of `1 master` (`ec2` instance) node only for now. The network is built of `1 VPC` with CIDR range `10.0.0.0/16` and `4 Subnets` with CIDR ranges `(public_1, 10.0.0.0/20)`, `(public_2, 10.0.16.0/20)`, `(private_1, 10.0.32.0/20)`, `(private_2, 10.0.48.0/20)`. The public subnets route outbound traffic via an `internet gateway` to the internet and private subnets route outbound traffic via a `NAT` proxy (`ec2` instance) to the internet. The private subnets are also connected to each other via a `VPC Endpoint`. I access machines on my private subnet via another `ec2` instance that acts as a bastion. Hence, There are a total of 3 machines.

- K8S Master Instance.
- Bastion Instance (SSH only)
- NAT Proxy Instance (Private Subnet --> Internet [Outbound Only])

#### AWS Setup Master Instance

I've attached a security group that forwards the ports listed in [kubernetes.io/docs/reference/networking/ports-and-protocols](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/networking/ports-and-protocols/). I've also created an IAM role (ec2 instance profile) and attached the policies listed [cloud-provider-aws.sigs.k8s.io/prerequisites](https://cloud-provider-aws.sigs.k8s.io/prerequisites/).
[image: the inbound rules forwarded on my master instance]

#### On Master Instance

1. I setup the hostname of the instance to the private ipv4 dns name with `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/hostname`.
2. I setup the iptables with `iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`.
3. I installed `containerd`, `kubelet`, `kubectl`, `kubeadm`.
4. I loaded the modules `br_netfilter` & `overlay`.
5. I setup kernal flags namely `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables  = 1`, `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1`, `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`.
6. I added `KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--node-ip=<ipv4_address> --cloud-provider=external` in `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/20-aws.conf`.
7. I added `--cloud-provider=external` to `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kubernetes-controller-manager.yaml` & `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`.
8. I initialized a fresh k8s cluster with `kubeadm init --token--ttl 0` and it initialised successfully.
9. I deployed `aws-vpc-cni-k8s` via `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/v1.16.4/config/master/aws-k8s-cni.yaml`.
10. I deployed `aws-cloud-controller-manager` via `kubectl apply -k 'github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-aws/examples/existing-cluster/base/?ref=master'`.

#### Problem

Both `aws-cloud-controller-manager` and `aws-vpc-cni` deployed successfully and showed no errors. While the node shows up as "Ready", I'm unable to get `coredns` working. It's unable to start. Neither `journalctl -u kubelet.service` nor `journalctl -u containerd.service` reveal anything about the source of problem. I believe my ports are forwarded correctly and I'm unsure what's causing `corends` to not run.

My assumption is that `coredns` pod is directing dns lookups from it's `/etc/resolv.conf` to my master node `/etc/resolv.conf` because of the config map `forward . /etc/resolv.conf`. The master node is is unaware of the cluster & therefore no lookup is successfull. I could be wrong here. I'm not sure to resolve this.

Here's relevant logs,

- `kubectl logs coredns-76f75df574-465x5 -n kube-system`

```bash
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration SHA512 = 591cf328cccc12bc490481273e738df59329c62c0b729d94e8b61db9961c2fa5f046dd37f1cf888b953814040d180f52594972691cd6ff41be96639138a43908
CoreDNS-1.11.1
linux/amd64, go1.20.7, ae2bbc2
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 908260726288404915.5102928999241227370. HINFO: read udp 10.0.43.148:39074->10.0.0.2:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 908260726288404915.5102928999241227370. HINFO: read udp 10.0.43.148:47632->10.0.0.2:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 908260726288404915.5102928999241227370. HINFO: read udp 10.0.43.148:34254->10.0.0.2:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 908260726288404915.5102928999241227370. HINFO: read udp 10.0.43.148:39274->10.0.0.2:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 908260726288404915.5102928999241227370. HINFO: read udp 10.0.43.148:49990->10.0.0.2:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 908260726288404915.5102928999241227370. HINFO: read udp 10.0.43.148:54792->10.0.0.2:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 908260726288404915.5102928999241227370. HINFO: read udp 10.0.43.148:46469->10.0.0.2:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 908260726288404915.5102928999241227370. HINFO: read udp 10.0.43.148:33147->10.0.0.2:53: i/o timeout
[INFO] plugin/kubernetes: pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.4/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
[INFO] plugin/kubernetes: Trace[597383834]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.4/tools/cache/reflector.go:231 (16-Mar-2024 09:09:06.572) (total time: 30002ms):
Trace[597383834]: ---"Objects listed" error:Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout 30001ms (09:09:36.574)
Trace[597383834]: [30.002080972s] [30.002080972s] END
[ERROR] plugin/kubernetes: pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.4/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.Namespace: failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
[INFO] plugin/kubernetes: pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.4/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
[INFO] plugin/kubernetes: Trace[1358557007]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.4/tools/cache/reflector.go:231 (16-Mar-2024 09:09:06.573) (total time: 30001ms):
Trace[1358557007]: ---"Objects listed" error:Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout 30001ms (09:09:36.574)
Trace[1358557007]: [30.001364092s] [30.001364092s] END
[ERROR] plugin/kubernetes: pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.4/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.Service: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
[INFO] plugin/kubernetes: pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.4/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.EndpointSlice: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/discovery.k8s.io/v1/endpointslices?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
[INFO] plugin/kubernetes: Trace[784641658]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.4/tools/cache/reflector.go:231 (16-Mar-2024 09:09:06.574) (total time: 30001ms):
Trace[784641658]: ---"Objects listed" error:Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/discovery.k8s.io/v1/endpointslices?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout 30000ms (09:09:36.575)
Trace[784641658]: [30.001209965s] [30.001209965s] END
[ERROR] plugin/kubernetes: pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.4/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.EndpointSlice: failed to list *v1.EndpointSlice: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/discovery.k8s.io/v1/endpointslices?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 908260726288404915.5102928999241227370. HINFO: read udp 10.0.43.148:33770->10.0.0.2:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 908260726288404915.5102928999241227370. HINFO: read udp 10.0.43.148:54282->10.0.0.2:53: i/o timeout
```

- `kubectl describe pod coredns-76f75df574-465x5 -n kube-system`

```bash
admin@ip-10-0-32-163:~$ kubectl describe pod  coredns-76f75df574-465x5 -n kube-system
Name:                 coredns-76f75df574-465x5
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000000000
Priority Class Name:  system-cluster-critical
Service Account:      coredns
Node:                 ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal/10.0.32.163
Start Time:           Sat, 16 Mar 2024 09:09:05 +0000
Labels:               k8s-app=kube-dns
                      pod-template-hash=76f75df574
Annotations:          <none>
Status:               Running
IP:                   10.0.43.148
IPs:
  IP:           10.0.43.148
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/coredns-76f75df574
Containers:
  coredns:
    Container ID:  containerd://cb07b34ca26b0b5d51dfcf658ba03fed0979346da243abd98ab8190a6df46800
    Image:         registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns:v1.11.1
    Image ID:      registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns@sha256:1eeb4c7316bacb1d4c8ead65571cd92dd21e27359f0d4917f1a5822a73b75db1
    Ports:         53/UDP, 53/TCP, 9153/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/UDP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      -conf
      /etc/coredns/Corefile
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sat, 16 Mar 2024 09:31:42 +0000
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Sat, 16 Mar 2024 09:24:46 +0000
      Finished:     Sat, 16 Mar 2024 09:26:40 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  8
    Limits:
      memory:  170Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     70Mi
    Liveness:     http-get http://:8080/health delay=60s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Readiness:    http-get http://:8181/ready delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/coredns from config-volume (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-5l9f6 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type                        Status
  PodReadyToStartContainers   True
  Initialized                 True
  Ready                       False
  ContainersReady             False
  PodScheduled                True
Volumes:
  config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      coredns
    Optional:  false
  kube-api-access-5l9f6:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:                 CriticalAddonsOnly op=Exists
                             node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                  ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  27m                   default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had untolerated taint {node.kubernetes.io/unreachable: }. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
  Normal   Scheduled         23m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kube-system/coredns-76f75df574-465x5 to ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal
  Normal   Created           23m                   kubelet            Created container coredns
  Normal   Started           23m                   kubelet            Started container coredns
  Warning  Unhealthy         23m                   kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.0.43.148:8181/ready": dial tcp 10.0.43.148:8181: i/o timeout (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Warning  Unhealthy         21m (x5 over 22m)     kubelet            Liveness probe failed: Get "http://10.0.43.148:8080/health": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Normal   Killing           21m                   kubelet            Container coredns failed liveness probe, will be restarted
  Normal   Pulled            21m (x2 over 23m)     kubelet            Container image "registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns:v1.11.1" already present on machine
  Warning  Unhealthy         13m (x80 over 23m)    kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.0.43.148:8181/ready": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Warning  BackOff           3m36s (x28 over 10m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container coredns in pod coredns-76f75df574-465x5_kube-system(73e7c967-cf8f-4ee5-b525-1839d64e5058)
```

- `kubectl get pods -A -o wide`

```bash
admin@ip-10-0-32-163:~$ kubectl get pods -A -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                                 READY   STATUS             RESTARTS         AGE   IP            NODE                                         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default       dnsutils                                                             1/1     Running            1 (65m ago)      10h   10.0.35.236   ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
kube-system   aws-cloud-controller-manager-czwrm                                   1/1     Running            4 (65m ago)      19h   10.0.32.163   ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
kube-system   aws-node-4rtrh                                                       2/2     Running            8 (65m ago)      19h   10.0.32.163   ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-76f75df574-465x5                                             0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   11 (4m24s ago)   43m   10.0.43.148   ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-76f75df574-b9r5t                                             0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   11 (2m53s ago)   43m   10.0.44.228   ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal                      1/1     Running            4 (65m ago)      19h   10.0.32.163   ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal            1/1     Running            4 (65m ago)      19h   10.0.32.163   ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal   1/1     Running            4 (65m ago)      19h   10.0.32.163   ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-6cg92                                                     1/1     Running            4 (65m ago)      19h   10.0.32.163   ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal            1/1     Running            4 (65m ago)      19h   10.0.32.163   ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
```

- `kubectl get all -A`

```bash
admin@ip-10-0-32-163:~$ kubectl get all -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
kube-system   pod/aws-cloud-controller-manager-8d4m9                                   1/1     Running   3 (2m17s ago)   17h
kube-system   pod/aws-node-lvl5p                                                       2/2     Running   4 (3m7s ago)    17h
kube-system   pod/coredns-76f75df574-jqjk4                                             0/1     Running   13 (38s ago)    10h
kube-system   pod/coredns-76f75df574-nbd9c                                             0/1     Running   13 (50s ago)    10h
kube-system   pod/dnsutils                                                             1/1     Running   1 (3m7s ago)    10h
kube-system   pod/etcd-ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal                      1/1     Running   14 (3m7s ago)   17h
kube-system   pod/kube-apiserver-ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal            1/1     Running   2 (3m7s ago)    17h
kube-system   pod/kube-controller-manager-ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal   1/1     Running   2 (3m7s ago)    17h
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-r2sh2                                                     1/1     Running   2 (3m7s ago)    17h
kube-system   pod/kube-scheduler-ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal            1/1     Running   5 (3m7s ago)    17h

NAMESPACE     NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.97.0.1    <none>        443/TCP                  17h
kube-system   service/kube-dns     ClusterIP   10.97.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   17h

NAMESPACE     NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                            AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/aws-cloud-controller-manager   1         1         1       1            1           node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane=   17h
kube-system   daemonset.apps/aws-node                       1         1         1       1            1           <none>                                   17h
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy                     1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux                   17h

NAMESPACE     NAME                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   deployment.apps/coredns   0/2     2            0           17h

NAMESPACE     NAME                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
kube-system   replicaset.apps/coredns-76f75df574   2         2         0       10h
```

- `sudo iptables -vnL`

```bash
admin@ip-10-0-32-163:~$ sudo iptables -vnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 576K packets, 102M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 5175  311K KUBE-PROXY-FIREWALL  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW /* kubernetes load balancer firewall */
 571K  100M KUBE-NODEPORTS  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes health check service ports */
 5175  311K KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW /* kubernetes externally-visible service portals */
 575K  102M KUBE-FIREWALL  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 KUBE-PROXY-FIREWALL  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW /* kubernetes load balancer firewall */
    0     0 KUBE-FORWARD  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding rules */
    0     0 KUBE-SERVICES  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
    0     0 KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW /* kubernetes externally-visible service portals */
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 580K packets, 110M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 7345  442K KUBE-PROXY-FIREWALL  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW /* kubernetes load balancer firewall */
 7345  442K KUBE-SERVICES  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
 579K  110M KUBE-FIREWALL  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain KUBE-FIREWALL (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       0    --  *      *      !127.0.0.0/8          127.0.0.0/8          /* block incoming localnet connections */ ! ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT

Chain KUBE-FORWARD (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding rules */ mark match 0x4000/0x4000
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain KUBE-KUBELET-CANARY (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain KUBE-NODEPORTS (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain KUBE-PROXY-CANARY (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain KUBE-PROXY-FIREWALL (3 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain KUBE-SERVICES (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 REJECT     6    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.96.0.10           /* kube-system/kube-dns:metrics has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:9153 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     17   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.96.0.10           /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns has no endpoints */ udp dpt:53 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     6    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.96.0.10           /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:53 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

- `kubectl cluster-info`

```bash
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://10.0.32.163:6443
CoreDNS is running at https://10.0.32.163:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'
```

- `cat /etc/resolve.conf` (on my master node)

```bash
admin@ip-10-0-32-163:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "resolvectl status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
nameserver 10.0.0.2
```

- `kubectl -n kube-system exec dnsutils -- cat /etc/resolv.conf` (on a test pod deployed to kube-system to debug dns)

```bash
admin@ip-10-0-32-163:~$ kubectl -n kube-system exec dnsutils -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
search kube-system.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
nameserver 10.97.0.10
options ndots:5
```

- `kubectl describe cm corends -n kube-system`

```bash
admin@ip-10-0-32-163:~$ kubectl describe cm coredns -n kube-system
Name:         coredns
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
Corefile:
----
.:53 {
    log
    errors
    health {
       lameduck 5s
    }
    ready
    kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
       pods insecure
       fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
       ttl 30
    }
    prometheus :9153
    forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
       max_concurrent 1000
    }
    cache 30
    loop
    reload
    loadbalance
}


BinaryData
====

Events:  <none>
```

#### Cluster information:

- Kubernetes version: `v1.29.2`
- Cloud being used: (put bare-metal if not on a public cloud) `AWS`
  Installation method: `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.96.0.0/16 --service-cidr=10.97.0.0/16 --token-ttl 0`
- Host OS: `Linux ip-10-0-32-163.ap-south-1.compute.internal 6.1.0-18-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- CNI and version: [aws-vpc-k8s-cni v1.16.4](https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/)
- CRI and version: `containerd containerd.io 1.6.28 ae07eda36dd25f8a1b98dfbf587313b99c0190bb`